# XPath event filter working in Event Viewer but not in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks, event-log

I'm trying to trigger a scheduled task with this XML:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
*[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetInfo']='S']]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

That query works fine if I use it to filter events in the Event Viewer, but is never triggered when used in a scheduled task.

The task runs if I invoke it manually in the Task Scheduler.

I've tried running the task as `SYSTEM`, `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` and as a local user.

I am able to successfully use other queries, like `*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4648)]]`.

I've also tried the alternative syntax `*[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetInfo'] and (Data='S')]]`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.